# Jackson - Wrap POJO in a wrapper class with metadata - Gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a model class that I want to wrap for a REST service to output.

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    // getter..setter;
}

public class Wrapper {
    private Model model;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    // getter..setter;
}

public class Converter extends StdConverter<Model, Wrapper> {
    @Override
    public Wrapper convert(Model model) {
        return new Wrapper(model, new Date());
    }
}
```

With the output being a json along the lines of

```
{
  "model": {
     "name" : "dave"
  },
  "date": "tuesday"
}
```

The issue is it seems to get stuck in a loop. Constantly trying to serialise the model, nesting within it self.

I've tried adding `@JsonSerialize(converter = Converter.class)`
and setting `module.addSerializer(Model.class, new StdDelegatingSerializer(new Converter()));` in my object mapper, but get the same results each time.

Using jackson 2.8.5

Comment: Is it not an option to first create the wrapper using the object and then serialize it?

Comment: @nille85, thats what we are trying to avoid!

Comment: I just think creating a wrapper first and then serialize it, is a more elegant solution but that's a matter of taste. I tried doing the same like you by creating a custom Serializer extending from StdSerializer but that also resulted in a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a proxy of `Model` and use that one in order to create a `Wrapper`. That way you can prevent the loop.

```
public class Converter extends StdConverter<Model, Wrapper> {

    @Override
    public Wrapper convert(Model model) {
        return new Wrapper(new ModelProxy(model), new Date());
    }
}
```

Implementation of ModelProxy:

```
public class ModelProxy {

    private final Model model;

    public ModelProxy(final Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return model.getName();
    }

}
```

Comment: Marked as the correct answer as this is the approach I used. Still have a feeling there should be a better way, but being a realist, this will suffice for now! Thanks nille85

Answer (score 0):

I would like to amend @nielle85's answer with an approach that reduces the amount of needed code.

The approach is to let `ModelProxy` extend `Model` and disable the conversion on it using an annotation, instead of having an aggregate class. That way, all that is needed is a copy constructor.

Example code:

```
@JsonSerialize(converter = ModelConverter.class)
public class Model {
   // Getters, setters and fields omitted.
}

@JsonSerialize(converter = Converter.None.class)
public class ModelProxy extends Model {
    public ModelProxy(Model model) {
        // Copy constructor
    }
}
```

The copy constructor could be trivially implemented and kept up-to-date using a bean-mapping framework such as Apache Beanutils or Dozer.